# R repeat only one element and change other elements

Tags: r, seq, rep

I need this:

```
"X","Y",151,"X","Y",152,"X","Y",153,"X","Y",154,....."X","Y",334
```

But I can only get this:

```
names<-c("X","Y",seq(152,334,by=1))
#"X","Y",151,152,153,154....334
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a vector of sequence ('v1'), replicate the vector (`c("X", "Y", "")`) by the `length` of 'v1' and `replace the`""` with 'v1'.

```
v1 <-  152:334
v2 <- rep(c("X", "Y", ""), length(v1))
v3 <- replace(v2, v2 == "", v1)
head(v3, 10)
#[1] "X"   "Y"   "152" "X"   "Y"   "153" "X"   "Y"   "154" "X"  
tail(v3, 10)
# [1] "331" "X"   "Y"   "332" "X"   "Y"   "333" "X"   "Y"   "334"
```

---

Or another option is replicate the string (`"X Y"`) by the `length` of 'v1', `rbind` with 'v1', concatenate (`c`) the matrix to a `vector`,  `scan` to split up the `"X Y"` to `"X", "Y"`.

```
scan(text=c(rbind(rep("X Y", length(v1)),  v1)), what = "", quiet=TRUE)
```